# CSS3 NOT and Sibling selector not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

From some reason the code below is working OK in FireFox, but in Chrome it does not (in Chrome I can see by inspect element that condition is met):

```css
.hiddenFields:not([style*="display:none"]):not([style*="display: none"]) ~ p.form-helper-t23 {
 opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: You missed to add your HTML.

Comment: Seems to work fine here. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/k579x42j/2/

Comment: Man, that is one *ugly* selector.

Comment: If I may take a guess, this is with a style attribute added by JavaScript, right? If so, better play it safe and add a class name instead.